# Tables showing up with two: 'one to many' relationships in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm looking through our data and there's a handful of tables in our oracle database that show up with two one to many relationships: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icGcV.png

I'm not sure why this would be happening, and is it something I should look into getting changed or fixed?

(I did not create this database, I am only trying to understand it!)

Comment: The image just shows two arrows.  You need to include more detail than this.

Comment: what more could I show? I don't want to post the tables themselves, I just want to understand why some tables would be linked with two relationships like this and others wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, let's see a very simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(
    id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name    VARCHAR2(10)
)
/    
CREATE TABLE marriages
(
    wife       NUMBER     REFERENCES persons(id),
    husband    NUMBER     REFERENCES persons(id)
)
/    
CREATE TABLE dogs
(
    id       NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name     VARCHAR2(10),
    owner    NUMBER     REFERENCES persons(id)
)
/
```

Here you have one table with two different FKs to the same table. At the same time you have another table with a single FK to the same table.
So, it's not a problem to fix, but a part of DB design to understand;
your DB can be well or bad designed, but the existence of such situations does not say anything about that.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I'm understanding, this simply happened in the database model because there was more than one foreign key from one single table to another single table. That makes sense, if I'm understanding correctly